# Tag synonym request: [fp] -> [functional-programming]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

[fp](/questions/tagged/fp) should be a synonym for [functional-programming](/questions/tagged/functional-programming).

Comment: [[tag:fp]] as a tag should have never existed...

Comment: Doesn't `fp` mean floating-point?

Comment: @BoPersson - I wondered if it meant function pointer...

Comment: I use it as short for "fun pointer" when I have pointer related problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synonyms are used when users started using two or more tags to mean the same thing; this could happen when somebody uses [drupal-view](/questions/tagged/drupal-view), and somebody else uses [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views) to mean the same thing, or when enough users keep using [dupal-views](/questions/tagged/dupal-views), instead of [drupal-views](/questions/tagged/drupal-views).

They are not used to allow to use a short for a tag, and avoid to enter more than 2 letters when writing a tag. There is already an autocomplete routine that avoids you need to enter all the tag name; you don't need to write the all the tag name, to add a new tag.

There is also a problem with tags/synonyms of just two letters: They are too ambiguous because they could have given more than one meaning, as awoodland shows in his answer.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think a synonym for this is a good idea. There's way too many possible acronyms for [fp](/questions/tagged/fp), even in the computing ones alone:

- functional programming
- function pointer
- floating point
- fixed precision (!)
- false positive
- Front Page
- ...

There's nothing currently tagged [fp](/questions/tagged/fp). It should stay that way.

Comment: Oh lawd, Front Page?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - just putting it out there :)